# scanning from an input file in C until reaching a certain character (#)?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, input, terminate

Simple question:

If i have a line in an input file that looks looks like:

```
Hello#Great#Day#Today
```

how can I scan in each word individually as its own array, in other words tell C to stop scanning when it reaches the # character and then go in the next iteration of the loop to scan the next word as a separate array?

Comment: I'd start by writing an algorithm (check) and then some *code*. if that doesn't work, bring it here and we'll see what we can do to help.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought it would be simple for someone more experienced than me to show me a way to implement this, but I guess the solution is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: Well here is a kickstart. 1. Find the size of the file (see `fseek()` and `ftell()`). 2. Allocate a single buffer large enough for the entire file +1 for a null-termiator (see `malloc()`). 3. Read the entire file into the buffer (see `freed()`). 4. Set a `0` terminator at the *end* of the buffer. And finally, loop over the buffer with `strtok()` using `"#"` as your delimiter. When finished, don't forget to free *just* the original memory block allocated in (2) above. Lookup all those APIs just mentioned and formulate your plan. Good luck.

Comment: Note. That should have been `fread()` . I'm always doing that. Sorry!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming you are reading through `stdin`. Definitely take a look at @Whoz kick start approach as well (very similar to this).

---

What you would want to do is create a dynamic array and populate it with every byte read through `stdin`. You would then want to create an array of character pointers that will point to the first character in every "word", where you define a word as every character before a `'#'` character (delimiter). You would then iterate through that array of characters and populate the array of character pointers with the memory addresses of the first character in each word.

Comment: *"...arr only points to the first character of each word."* No it doesn't. This stores the address of a loop-scope variable (`byte` in the char array. It is **undefined behavior** to dereference this pointer once the loop exits. If you want to do this, a full-file buffer with every `#` replaced with a `0` would be considerably better (not to mention, be much less likely to crash your process).

Comment: @WhozCraig, I realize now how wrong my solution was -- don't know what I was thinking. Fixed.

Comment: Thats considerably better. Your answer and Magn3s1um's together essentially spell out the kickstart I mentioned in general comment.

Comment: @WhozCraig, oh I did not notice you previously mentioned this approach. I'll make a note of that.

Answer (score 2):

Use strtok() to tokenize your input by the specified character.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

```
 char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
 char * pch;
 printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
 pch = strtok (str,"#");
  while (pch != NULL)
 {
 printf ("%s\n",pch);
 pch = strtok (NULL, "#");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In two stages, I have used something like this:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

//tokenizing a string
int GetCount(char *in, char *delim, int *m);
int GetStrings(char *in, char *delim, int count, char **out);  


void main(void)
{
    int count, maxlen, i;
    char inpString[]={"Hello#Greatest#Day#Today"};
    char *resultBuf[10];

    //get a count of strings to store
    count = GetCount(inpString, "#", &maxlen);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        resultBuf[i] = calloc(maxlen+1, sizeof(char));  
    }

    //Store strings in arrays
    GetStrings(inpString, "#", count, resultBuf);

    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", resultBuf[i]);
        free(resultBuf[i];
    }             

}
     //Gets count of tokens (delimited strings)
int GetCount(char *in, char *delim, int *m)
{
    char *buf=0;
    char temp1[10]={0};
    char *inStr;
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0, keepMax = 0;
    if(in)
    {

        inStr = calloc(strlen(in)+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(inStr, in);
        if(strlen(inStr) > 1)
        {
            count = 0;
            buf = strtok(inStr, delim);
            while(buf)
            {
                strcpy(temp1, buf);
                max = strlen(temp1);
                (max > keepMax)?(keepMax = max):(keepMax == keepMax);
                count++;
                buf = strtok(NULL, delim);
            }
            *m = keepMax;
        }
        free(inStr);
    }
    return count;
}
     //Gets array of strings
int GetStrings(char *in, char *delim, int count, char **out)
{
    char *buf=0;
    char *inStr;
    int i = 0;
    if(in)
    {

        inStr = calloc(strlen(in)+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(inStr, in);
        if(strlen(inStr) > 1)
        {
            buf = strtok(inStr, delim);
            while(buf)
            {
                strcpy(out[i], buf);
                buf = strtok(NULL, delim);
                i++;
            }
        }
        free(inStr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```