# split array of char with delimiter '#' and save in another array

Tags: c, linux

I have a problem.  I receive a response from a server as an array of chars. Ex: `555#200#`.  I split the array into `555` and `200` because that is my command.  I want to save that command to another array but I get bad results.  Here's my code:

```
void READ_FROM_SERVER(void) {
    int read_vkluci = read(sock_descriptor, read_from_server, sizeof(read_from_server));

    if (read_vkluci < 0)
        printf("Failed reading  bytes from server\n");

    printf(" %s \n", read_from_server);

    if(read_vkluci>0){
        char** tokens;
        printf("naredbi=%s \n\n", read_from_server);
        tokens = str_split(read_from_server, '#');

        if (tokens){
            int i;

            for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++){
                printf("naredba=%s\n", *(tokens + i));
                naredbi_odelno[i]=  *(tokens + i);
                printf("naredba_odelno=%s\n", naredbi_odelno[i]);
                brojnacomandi++;
                //free(*(tokens + i));
            }

            printf("\n");
            //free(tokens);
        }
    }

    int p;
    for(p=0;p<brojnacomandi;p++){

        if (naredbi_odelno[p]==201) {
            nadvoresna_komanda = VKLUCI;
            printf("VKLUCEN UVLEKUVAC!!!!");
        }
        if (naredbi_odelno[p]==200) {
            nadvoresna_komanda = ISKLUCI;
            printf("ISLKUCEN UVLEKUVAC!!!!");
        }

        if (naredbi_odelno[p]==96) {
            printf("TCP_CONN_OK!!!\n");
        }
        if (naredbi_odelno[p]==211) {
            makeTXpaket(STACK_1);
            p_tx_buffer_ = &tx_buffer[1];
            nbytes = write(fd, tx_buffer, *p_tx_buffer_);
            if (nbytes != tx_buffer[1]) {
                /* problem! */
                printf("error writing on serial port!!!");
            }
            printf("PRIMAM....\n");
            isprateno=0;
        }

        if (naredbi_odelno[p]==210) {
        makeTXpaket( RETURN);
        p_tx_buffer_ = &tx_buffer[1];
        nbytes = write(fd, tx_buffer, *p_tx_buffer_);
        if (nbytes != tx_buffer[1]) {
                /* problem! */
                printf("error writing on serial port!!!");
        }
        printf("VRAKAM....\n");
        isprateno=0;
        }
        //  else  {
        //      printf("TCP_NOT_OK!!!!\n");
        //      close(sock_descriptor);
        //      CONECT_T0_SERVER();
        //  }
        Clean_read_from_server_buff();
        Clean_naredbi_odelno();
    }
}

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim){
    char** result    = 0;
    size_t count     = 0;
    char* tmp        = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp){
        if (a_delim == *tmp){
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result){
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, "#");

        while (token){
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, "#");
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The server sends me only 555#, but I get in `naredba_odelno` bad result! Any idea why that is happening?

How do I make `naredba_odelno` = `naredba` because `naredba` is good!

output:

`naredbi=555#`

`naredba=555`

`naredbi_odelno=` ...... bad results why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C split a char array into different variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349270/c-split-a-char-array-into-different-variables)

Comment: Did you bother using a debugger?

Comment: in debuger i see that '555' but hex value is change!why?

Comment: Also discussion with similar focus [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191379/scanning-from-an-input-file-in-c-until-reaching-a-certain-character/18193951#18193951)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is that you're reading off the end of the input data. Note that `read` does not nul-terminate the string, so your `printf` statement is immediately broken.

Try this:

```
int read_vkluci = read(sock_descriptor, read_from_server, sizeof(read_from_server)-1);
```

and this

```
read_from_server[read_vkluci] = '\0';
printf("naredbi=%s \n\n", read_from_server);
```

BTW, `sizeof(read_from_server)` will only work correctly if `read_from_server` is an array type. If it's a pointer to a buffer then that's broken too.

Comment: naredbi=555#
naredba=555
naredba_odelno=any simbol not 555